# Google Sheet Integration with Chrome Extension using

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-chrome-extension, google-sheets-api

I'm creating an application for this website.

here the **manifest.json** file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Smarkets Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Adds a button to the Smarkets website.",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "identity", "https://sheets.googleapis.com/"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://smarkets.com/listing/sport/basketball?period=today"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icon16.png",
      "48": "icon48.png",
      "128": "icon128.png"
    }
  },
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "client_ID",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here the **content.js** file

```
async function extractMatchDetails() {   // Select all event tiles   console.log("hi");   let matches = [];   const eventTiles = document.querySelectorAll(".event-tile");

  // Iterate over each event tile   eventTiles.forEach((tile) => {
    // Extract relevant information from the tile
    const teams = tile.querySelectorAll(".team-name");
    const homeTeam = teams[0] ? teams[0].textContent.trim() : "";
    const awayTeam = teams[1] ? teams[1].textContent.trim() : "";

    const scores = tile.querySelectorAll(".score-block .score");
    const homeScore = scores.length > 0 ? scores[0].textContent.trim() : "";
    const awayScore = scores.length > 1 ? scores[1].textContent.trim() : "";

    const contractItems = tile.querySelectorAll(".contract-item");
    const homeOffer = contractItems[0]
      ? contractItems[0]
          .querySelector(".price.tick.buy.enabled")
          .textContent.trim()
      : "";
    const homeBid = contractItems[0]
      ? contractItems[0]
          .querySelector(".price.tick.sell.enabled")
          .textContent.trim()
      : "";
    const awayOffer = contractItems[1]
      ? contractItems[1]
          .querySelector(".price.tick.buy.enabled")
          .textContent.trim()
      : "";
    const awayBid = contractItems[1]
      ? contractItems[1]
          .querySelector(".price.tick.sell.enabled")
          .textContent.trim()
      : "";

    // Log the extracted details to the console
    console.log("Home Team:", homeTeam);
    console.log("Away Team:", awayTeam);
    console.log("Home Score:", homeScore);
    console.log("Away Score:", awayScore);
    console.log("Home Offer:", homeOffer);
    console.log("Home Bid:", homeBid);
    console.log("Away Offer:", awayOffer);
    console.log("Away Bid:", awayBid);
    console.log("---------------------------------");

    const match = {
      homeTeam,
      awayTeam,
      homeScore,
      awayScore,
      homeOffer,
      homeBid,
      awayOffer,
      awayBid,
    };

    // Add the match to the array
    matches.push(match);   });   console.log("hitting the api call now")   chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "updateSheet", matches });   console.log("hitting done") }

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {   if (message.action === "extractMatchDetails") {
    extractMatchDetails();   } });
```

here's the **popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Smarkets Extension</title>
  <style>
    button {
      padding: 10px 20px;
      font-size: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="startButton">Start</button>

  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here the **popup.js** file

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
  
    startButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: 'extractMatchDetails'});
      });
    });
  });
```

Alright I'm learning creating the chrome extensions. So The issue I'm facing is I can extract the details but I'm not able to update the google online sheet.

So this extension auto runs after 4 seconds and update the records into the excel sheet.

Please help me thank you